# How to select character string 9999999 as 99 999 99 in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to select character string 9999999 as 99 999 99 using select command in sql?
I have tried to solve the problem using `to_char`, `to_number` functions but unable to get results.

Comment: What's the logic of inserting the space between the string?

Comment: Solve that in your logic and not with SQL

Comment: Turn it into a string (it probably is a string anyway, but with only digits as valid characters) and use substr to pull the three character groups and add spaces between them. A single example is also not helpful as it's hopelessly ambiguous -- if you can't describe in words the logic that you want to implement then you certainly can't write the code for it.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you're doing, but if you only want to present numbers this way, use the `TO_CHAR` with specific `nls_numeric_characters` and the `G` format mask:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR('9999999', '999G999G99', 'nls_numeric_characters='', '' ') AS val
FROM dual;
```

```
VAL        
------------
  99 999 99
```

`G` is the `Group separator`, which is specified by the second character in `nls_numeric_characters` session setting (first one is the decimal separator). You can also alter it with `ALTER SESSION`:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_numeric_characters = ", ";

> session SET altered.

SELECT TO_CHAR('9999999', '999G999G99') AS val FROM dual;
```

```
VAL        
------------
  99 999 99
```

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @value varchar(30)= '9999999'
declare @value1 varchar(30)
set @value1=  convert(varchar(30),cast(@value as money),1)
select REPLACE (@value1,',',' ')
```